# Change zIndex in HighChart

Tags: highcharts

using Highchart, how can we change the **zIndex** for a line according to its state,  or dynamically from a **click** event ?

I tried :

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
               states: {
                     select: {

                            lineWidth: 2,
                            zIndex:10
                     }
               },
```

with : `this.setState(this.state === 'select' ? '' : 'select');` in the **Click** event but it doesn't work.

Comment: Looking at the HighCharts source code (and at the documentation here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.states.hover) it seems like the only attribute that's allowed to change for the series is lineWidth, there seems to be no built in functionality for any other attributes. If you would like help with a "hack" I may be able to figure something out.

Comment: If you don't mind taking the time, I'd like to know your solution. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, it's definitely not pretty, but I couldn't find a way to actually set the zIndex, so I had to do some maneuvering to fake it and bring each series to the front in a certain order. Here's the snippet to include:

```
Highcharts.Series.prototype.setState = (function (func) {
        return function () {
            if (arguments.length>0){
                if (arguments[0] !== ''){
                    if (typeof this.options.states[arguments[0]]['zIndex'] !== 'undefined'){
                        this.options.oldZIndex = this.group.zIndex;
                        this.group.zIndex = this.options.states[arguments[0]]['zIndex'];
                    }
                }else{
                    if (typeof this.options['oldZIndex'] !== "undefined"){
                        this.group.zIndex = this.options['oldZIndex'];
                    }
                }
                var order = [], i = 0;
                $.each(this.chart.series, function(){
                    order.push({id:i,zIndex:this.group.zIndex,me:this});
                    i++;
                });
                order.sort(function(a,b){return (a.zIndex>b.zIndex) ? 1 : -1;});
                $.each(order, function(){
                    this.me.group.toFront();
                });
                func.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        };
    } (Highcharts.Series.prototype.setState));
```

And here's the JSFiddle demonstrating:

http://jsfiddle.net/G9d9H/9/

Let me know if that's what you needed.

Comment: Also, if you're going to be using this in combination with my answer to your other question, you should put this hack before the other one in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution is to set the series.group.toFront() method on click (I prefer to use it on mouseover)

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                click: function () {
                    this.group.toFront();//bring series to front when hovered over
                }
            }
        }
    }
```